# After you "are finished that"/"are finished with that"/"have finished that", brush your teeth

Tags: grammar

I've been hearing constructs of the form, "are *_*_ed that," which sound wrong to me.  To my ear, the awkwardness would be dispelled if the word "are" was replaced with "have," or "with" inserted before "that."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly occurs, perhaps more in AmEng than in BrEng. If it sounds awkward, it's because the present and past perfect form is normally found with the auxiliary verb *have* rather than *be*. Exceptions are rare.

Comment: It definitely sounds wrong in American English. I'd say "if you are finished that" is not grammatical.

Comment: @PeterShor: But 'Are you finished with that?'